# How to add a custom accessory view?

Tags: ios, swift

I'd like to replace apple's default cell accessory view with my own. My code is below:

```
    var image = UIImage(named: "arrow.pdf")
    var imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
    cell.accessoryView = imageView
```

When I run the code, I don't see the arrow image. Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: If you want to achieve this through storyboard, just set the image view inside the storyboard and then give it a tag(e.g.: 5). Then you can access it in **cellForRow...** with **cell.view(withTag: 5)**

Comment: And, another question: why is your "image" a ***pdf***?

Comment: Hmm, I think my code is not working because it is a pdf? I think it has to be a png or a jpeg. Let me look into this. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Is `image` nil?

Comment: Yes it gives an error saying its nil

Comment: If you are using a PDF inside a .xcassets asset catalog, just use the name, with no extension. The vector PDF is rendered to the correct bitmap scales at build time.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try giving frame to your imageview

```
imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, Y: 0, width: 40, Height: 40)
```

And also you are not supposed to use .pdf as an image

Comment: Hi, I've added the frame and still don't see the arrow.

Comment: Adding it to the cell is helpful... **cell.addSubview(imageView)**

Comment: ok got it you are using image "arrow.pdf" well PDF is not an image

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. I needed to provide the bundle for which to find the image.

```
UIImage(named: "name", in: Bundle.(for: something.self), compatibleWith: nil)
```

NOTE: The arrow showed up correctly, even though it is a .pdf